# JavaScript: Websocket Error after deploying to Openshift

Tags: javascript, websocket, openshift

My code when deployed locally connects to `Websocket` endpoint as

```
 var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/tweetstream/tweets');
```

I deployed this to `Openshift` and the `URL` changes to http://map-tweetstream.rhcloud.com/tweetstream/

Now I start to see  `WebSocket Error [object Event]` error, so in `Developer Tools(Chrome) -> Console`, I try to connect to this websocket as

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://'+ document.location.host + document.location.pathname + 'tweets');
  connection.onopen = function() {
    connection.send('brazil');
  };
  connection.onerror = function(error) {
    console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
  };
  connection.onmessage = function(e) {
    var parse = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var coordinates = parse["geo"]["coordinates"];
    console.log("coordinates:" + JSON.stringify(coordinates, undefined, 2));
  };
```

and what I get back is

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://map-tweetstream.rhcloud.com/tweetstream/tweets' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
WebSocket Error [object Event]
```

where I see

```
document.location.host
"map-tweetstream.rhcloud.com"
document.location.pathname
"/tweetstream/"
```

What is the possible issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the websocket connection to port 8000 on your application url, not port 80.

```
ws://map-tweetstream.rhcloud.com:8000/tweetstream/tweets
```